# Subsetting rows from a data frame in R using []

Tags: r, subset

To subset rows from a data frame, inserting the condition in the first part of [ , ] seems to be the reference method, and inserting this condition inside "which()" seems to be useless.
However, in the presence of missing data, why is the first method not working, while the "which method" does, as in the following example?

```
df <- data.frame(var1=c(1,2,3,NA,NA), var2=c(4,0,5,2,3), var3=c(1,2,3,0,6))
testvar1<-df[df$var1==3,]
testvar1.which<-df[which(df$var1==3),]
```

testvar1

|  | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 5 | 3 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA.1 | NA | NA | NA |

testvar1.which

|  | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 5 | 3 |

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that `which` suppresses `NA` values by default, whereas a straightforward logical test will return a vector of the same length as the input with `NA` preserved. Compare:

```r
df$var1 == 3
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA    NA

which(df$var1 == 3)
#> [1] 3
```

If you subset the data frame with the first result, the first two rows are dropped as expected (because they correspond to `FALSE`) and the third row is kept because it is `TRUE`, which is also expected. The last two rows are where the confusion comes in. If you subset a data frame with an `NA`, you don't get a `NULL` result, you get an `NA` result, which is different. The two rows at the bottom are `NA` rows, which you get if you subset a data frame with `NA` values.

Comment: Thanks. But why is it often told that the version without which has to be used preferably? (In this situation I would choose the which option.)

Comment: It doesn't _have_ to be used preferably - it comes down to what the use case is and how you want NA values to be handled. Using `which` when it isn't required produces more verbose and less efficient code. Also, we often don't want `NA` values to be silently dropped (as `which` does) - we want to know about them and handle them explicitly.